# How would I display 5 vowels in a row with grep from a file?

Tags: shell

I tried to do this, but it does not work. It returns nothing, rather than a list of characters.

```
grep  ?*\[aeiouAEIOU]\{5\}?* words
```

Comment: But each line that matches your pattern will be written to the standard output.  Your title indicates you wish to display just the 5 vowels.  Please clarify, perhaps by showing an example of your desired output - and you should also add the contents of words, or at least, a sample of those contents.

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed that you want to display lines with 5 vowels in a row.

```
grep  "[aeiouAEIOU]\{5\}" words
```

You don't need a `\` on the `[`. I have no idea what the `?*`s are for. And you need to quote it to stop the shell from interpreting the `*`s and `?`s.

Comment: That is OK, it is tradition no this site to click the ✓ if an answer does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -o -E '[aeiouAEIOU]{5}' words
```

I suspect that the problem is that the stars in your syntax were filename-expanded by the shell and grep didn't see them, plus you escaped an opening bracket and did not escape the matching closing one. But why use the complicated syntax when there is a simpler one?

Answer (score 0):

To display **only** the five vowels, use the `-o` switch.

The switch `-E` allows to use braces directly (unescaped).

For case insensitivity you use the `-i` switch.

So e.g.

```
echo "AKAAJEJEaeiooXXX" | grep -Eio '[aeiou]{5}'
```

will display Eaeio. Without the -o switch, all the line will be output.

If you want to display the line only if it contains 5 vowels (i.e. not six), it's a bit more complicated; you need to specify that the five vowels mustn't touch other vowels. And manage the border cases where they touch the beginning or the end of the line.

```
grep -Ei '([^aeiou]|^)[aeiou]{5}([^aeiou]|$)'
```

This prevents using the -o switch, since the "nonmatching" border is now part of the found pattern. You can use the switch and then use a pipe to a second grep with five vowels only to further refine the output.