# grep to find lines that contain six or more non-vowel characters in a row

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Using `grep` and regular expressions, I need to output all lines in a file that contain at least six characters in a row that aren't vowels. This includes any consonants, punctuation, numbers, etc.

Comment: Okay. Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: _do my homework for me please_

Comment: Would you please click [edit] and add to the original question what you're written so far? It's always best, FYI, to expand your original question, which assures all can see the enhancement, rather than reply-by-Comment. Comments pile up, and scroll under the screen after a while.

Comment: Relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421103/117549

Comment: In what locale? Å, Ä and Ö are vowels...

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

`Ex="[^AEIOUaeiou]"; grep -E "$Ex$Ex$Ex$Ex$Ex$Ex" myfile`

Comment: Why the `-E`? Unless, of course, you instead did `grep -E "$Ex{6}"`, but that would render the use of that variable useless.

Comment: `grep -E "[^AEIOUaeiou]{6}" myfile`

Comment: Or `grep -iE '[^aeiou]{6}'`

Comment: -E means use expression (egrep can be used too). And yes, the use of {6} and -i is more eloquent than a variable.